# Можно ли создать веб сервер на Android, который будет обмениваться json файлами?

Tags: java, android

возник такой вопрос. Можно ли сделать веб сервер, который будет отвечать на запросы от клиента и принимать и отправлять JSON файлы?
P.S. Я делал раньше клиентскую часть, но вот насчет сервера мало информации нашел.

Comment: зачем делать веб сервер на андроиде?

Comment: @tym32167 Возникла задача, для обмена Json файлами с клиентом, по http. Клиент всего один.

Comment: кто такой клиент? Кто с кем и чем должен обмениваться и для чего?

Comment: @tym32167 надо c android устройства обрабатывать GET и POST запросы с другого приложения(которое является клиентом). Проблема в том, что клиентское приложение может отправлять данные только по http протоколу. Поэтому я и задал вопрос о возможности реализации такого на Android.

Comment: У вас у устройства будет статический IP? Или DNS?  Как клиент его найдет? Что за задача то стоит, зачем поднимать сервер на устройстве?

Comment: Сервер поднимается на другом железе, JSON обменивается по HTTP.

Comment: @tym32167 У устройства статический IP. Задача стоит так: обработка QR кода по протоколу http, который приходит с терминала. По-другому QR код не передать. В приложении уже есть сокет сервер, но он не обрабатывает http запросы. Сервер на другом железе в данном случае поднимать не выгодно.

Comment: @tym32167 мне по сути надо узнать в целом ли можно такое реализовать или нет. Я знаю, что так не делают, но здесь надо сделать именно так.

Comment: Я не пробовал, но пишут, что можно такое сделать. [How to create a HTTP server in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6329468/312041), [Creating a local HTTP server on android](https://medium.com/hacktive-devs/creating-a-local-http-server-on-android-49831fbad9ca)

Comment: @tym32167, Спасибо буду разбираться)